# IntelliJ I want to run python file in the terminal instead of the run window

Tags: python, intellij-idea

When bug hunting in a python script, i often find myself running a script multiple times per minute with a key binding. This works fine, and as i am used to with other editors.
However, when i press run(or key binding), i want to run the file in the terminal, that is already there at the bottom of my screen. Instead the terminal is replaced with the run window.
The run window has a few disadvantages:

1. There is no history, i cant see the last run.
2. I cant run terminal commands, so i have to either close it or open the terminal in another place on my screen.

**How can i change the settings so that when i press run, a run command for the current python file is executed in the terminal, instead of opening the run window?**

Comment: To add, i have had to change editor to Intellij because of my work, and i must say that i hate it. Nothing seems intuitive, and i have to google things any time I want to change some settings.